# MySql not working in Wamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Last week my [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) not working properly when I start it, it goes yellow.. and local host working fine but when I go though phpmyadmin its not working...

After that I try to go on mysql data folder in wamp and delete following files

```
    ib_logfile0
    ib_logfile1
    ibdata1
```

And the restart all service it working and goes green but my all database not working.. daily I do that for starting the service and import all the database daily for working

please suggest me the solution of this....

Comment: Did you install skype recently? Wamp has problems starting up when Skype is running.

Comment: i already change the skype port number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the wampserver 2.5 uninstall it and
try to follow the instruction on the video [(click here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgcW4h6ZAro)  better to understand and follow the instruction carefully

still got error's? I suggest use [wampserver 2.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/) because wampserver 2.5 has lots of bugs and errors

HOPE it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the files that MySQL uses to store the database -- of course your databases aren't going to work. I suggest you restore your databases from a backup. There's no way around it; as long as you are deleting the database files, you're going to have trouble using the database.

About the problems logging in through phpMyAdmin, you can search here for the actual error message or open another question and perhaps get that problem resolved as well.